# Get Record Using Ajax .All record Display AfterClick On Check Box To Get Total Problam

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Get Record Using Ajax. All record Display After checked On NetAmount
>   Checked  Box To Get Total Problam in NetAmount Textbox.

Get Record Using Ajax. All record Display After checked On NetAmount Checked  Box To Get Total Problam in NetAmount Textbox. 
[image]
My.js

```
 //For Get Record
        <script>
        function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
        } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getpopup.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
        }
        </script>

        // For Get Total
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".main").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        $(".main:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        if (total == 0) {
        $('#TotalCost').val('');
        }
        else {
        $('#TotalCost').val('$' + total);
        }
        });
        });

        </script>

<input type="text" class="input" name="NetAmount" id="TotalCost">
    //Ajax Call After Diaplay Record Here
     <div id="txtHint"><b> </b></div>
```

my.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("session_start.php");
include("title_name.php");
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>SrNo</th>
<th>EntryDate</th>
<th>NetAmount</th>
</tr>
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE Credit_id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$SrNo =$row['SrNo'];
$EntryDate = $row['EntryDate'];
$NetAmount =$row['NetAmount'];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $SrNo ?></td>
<td><?php echo $EntryDate ?></td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in main" id="filled-in-box" value="<?php echo $NetAmount ?>">
<label for="filled-in-box"><?php echo $NetAmount ?></label>
</td>
</tr>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Checkbook  chacked  To get Total In Net Amount Text Box..